# Does PhoneGap work on all versions of Android and iOS?

Tags: cordova

Does PhoneGap work on all versions of Android and iOS?

Answer (score 1):

I think this document from Phonegap website gives a good idea.

http://phonegap.com/about/feature

Adding on to that. Looking at the API's (EG http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/cordova_accelerometer_accelerometer.md.html#Accelerometer)

Answer (score 1):

1) Android 2.1 - API level 7

2) BlackBerry OS5 - but the browser sucks so OS6 is more realistic

3) iOS currently 3.X but when we release PhoneGap 2.0 in July that iOS version will bump to
   4.2. Since over 90% of users are on iOS 5.X it isn't a big deal.

These all are Minimum versions of Android, IOS, BlackBerry-.